# LINQ Left join Query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying converting sql query into LINQ but after write query unable to fetch record from resultset

```
SELECT T.ServiceOrderNo,T.STATUS, T.SubStatus,T.orderVersion,T.OrderDate
  ,@pid, T.EventID, 'FOI'    
 FROM #temp1 T     
 LEFT JOIN Tbl_Service_Order_Progress O  ON T.ServiceOrderNo  DATABASE_DEFAULT = O.ServiceOrderNo 
  AND O.PARENTID = @pid    
  AND O.ServiceOrderType  = 'FOI'    
 WHERE O.ServiceOrderNo  IS NULL
```

Above Query following  I'm trying in LINQ

```
var lstInsertFOI = (from i in lstFOI
                    join j in lstSOP on i.fulfilmentOrderItemIdentifier equals j.ServiceOrderNo into res
                                from subRight in res.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                where subRight.ParentId == parentId && subRight.ServiceOrderNo == null && subRight.ServiceOrderType.Equals("FOI")
                                select new
                                {
                                    ServiceOrderNo = subRight.ServiceOrderNo == null ? i.fulfilmentOrderItemIdentifier : subRight.ServiceOrderNo,
                                    EventStatus = i.status,
                                    EventSubStatus = i.subStatus,
                                    OrderVersion = i.orderVersion,
                                    EVENTRECEIVEDDATE = i.orderDate,
                                    ParentId = parentId,
                                    EventID = i.eventID,
                                    ServiceOrderType = "FOI",                                    
                                }).ToList();
```

above linq query does not fetch expected result, which should return number of records from lstFOI list, but returns no record. Is the linq query correct?

Comment: It seems like you are joining tables incorrectly. Are you working with context entities, or with two filled collections? Can you provide used entities class definitions?

Comment: lstFOI is a object of List<OrderItemDetails> where OrderItemDetails is a database table ,   lstSOP is a object of List<TBL_SERVICE_ORDER_PROGRESS> where TBL_SERVICE_ORDER_PROGRESS is db table and fulfilmentOrderItemIdentifier is same as ServiceOrderNo.

Answer (score 0):

Let start with SQL query.

```
LEFT JOIN Tbl_Service_Order_Progress O
ON T.ServiceOrderNo = O.ServiceOrderNo 
    AND O.PARENTID = @pid AND O.ServiceOrderType  = 'FOI'
```

is equivalent to

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Tbl_Service_Order_Progress 
    WHERE PARENTID = @pid AND ServiceOrderType  = 'FOI') O
ON T.ServiceOrderNo = O.ServiceOrderNo
```

then

```
WHERE O.ServiceOrderNo  IS NULL
```

means that the query is actually using *anti-join*, i.e. include all the records from the left side that **do not** have a matching records from the right side.

With all that in mind, the equivalent LINQ query should be like this:

```
var lstInsertFOI = (
    from i in lstFOI
    join j in lstSOP
        .Where(e => e.ParentId == parentId && subRight.ServiceOrderType == "FOI")
    on i.fulfilmentOrderItemIdentifier equals j.ServiceOrderNo into res
    where !res.Any()
    select new
    {
        ServiceOrderNo = i.fulfilmentOrderItemIdentifier,
        EventStatus = i.status,
        EventSubStatus = i.subStatus,
        OrderVersion = i.orderVersion,
        EVENTRECEIVEDDATE = i.orderDate,
        ParentId = parentId,
        EventID = i.eventID,
        ServiceOrderType = "FOI",                                    
    }).ToList();
```